# How to see all columns in reporting services

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2005

I have a reporting services file with a lot of columns. The problem is that I can't see all of them in the layout view, they are outside the part of the window I can scroll to. Does anyone have a tip on how to be able to edit them?

I can't increase the size of the window, I am already at max with 400 cm.

I am using Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: Hmm? I've never seen that happen before? Sounds like your designer / VStudio is bugged. Tried restarting, disabling addons, min/maximizing, etc yet? PS. It's confusing that you speak of "scrolling" as well as "centimeters", what do you mean by "at max with 400 cm"?

Comment: I have tried restarting. If I try to increase the size of the window i get an error complaining about it being an invalid value.